# R package on CRAN: reference online images in vignette such that "Internet resources should fail gracefully"

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, cran

CRAN has the following policy: Internet resources should fail gracefully.

I have an accepted package with vignettes that use Rmarkdown. One of the vignettes involve a lot of images, so rather than embed the raw images in the vignette, I reference the images on Flickr (to keep the package size small enough to be hosted on CRAN). Every half year or so, I'll get a message from the CRAN maintainers that the package is not failing gracefully on one of their servers:

```
     Could not fetch
https://live.staticflickr.com/65535/52281215570_5f9cc90a12_o.png
     HttpExceptionRequest Request {
      host = "live.staticflickr.com"
      port = 443
      secure = True
      requestHeaders = []
      path = "/65535/52281215570_5f9cc90a12_o.png"
      queryString = ""
      method = "GET"
      proxy = Nothing
      rawBody = False
      redirectCount = 10
      responseTimeout = ResponseTimeoutDefault
      requestVersion = HTTP/1.1
     }
      (ConnectionFailure Network.Socket.getAddrInfo (called with
preferred socket type/protocol: AddrInfo {addrFlags = [AI_ADDRCONFIG],
addrFamily = AF_UNSPEC, addrSocketType = Stream, addrProtocol = 0,
addrAddress = <assumed to be undefined>, addrCanonName = <assumed to be
undefined>}, host name: Just "live.staticflickr.com", service name: Just
"443"): does not exist (Name or service not known))
     Error: processing vignette
'Ex-04-Webscraping-Online-Data-Files.Rmd' failed with diagnostics:
     pandoc document conversion failed with error 61
```

What is the proper way to make this fail gracefully? Again, I am pointing to the images online.

Thanks.

Comment: I would try asking [R-package-devel](https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/r-package-devel). Quoting from that web page, my emphasis: *This list is to get help about package development in R. The goal of the list is to provide a forum for learning about the package development process. We hope to build a community of R package developers who can help each other solve problems, and reduce some of the burden on the CRAN maintainers. **If you are having problems developing a package or passing R CMD check, this is the place to ask!***

Comment: One alternative would be to show these vignettes only on the package website (if you have one). You can put them in `.Rbuildignore` so that they are not built in the source package but they will still be used by `pkgdown`. However, they won't appear on the package CRAN page and won't be available with `vignette()`.

Comment: Do you absolutely **need** to provide images, or could your vignettes be complemented with "live" sample code that generates the images?    Next question:  would it be possible to reduce the resolution, color depth, etc. in your images to the point that they **could** be included in the package data?

Comment: Thanks @RuiBarradas, I will try the R-package-devel mailing list if I can't crowdsource a solution here.  Thanks @bretauv, I'd like for the vignettes to appear on the CRAN website, so `.Rbuildignore` will not work.  @carl-witthoft, yes I will need the images in the vignettes; I've already reduced the resolution to the least possible already.

Comment: Here is a hack that I use to prevent `R CMD check` from failing to fetch web images: https://github.com/yihui/formatR/blob/fa1f841002de92f41f0f78d32f0804f17aa7d204/vignettes/formatR.Rmd#L123-L137 (That is, comment out the images during `R CMD check`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @rui-barradas has suggested, I posted to the r-package-devel listserv to solicit help.  Ivan Krylov [suggested](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-package-devel/2023q4/009650.html) using the option `self-contained: false` option in the `Rmd` file yaml header to not embed the images.  Unfortunately, this also applies to the CSS style sheets.  This at least prevents the pandoc error when creating the html file when internet resources aren't available.